# Relation Between Opportunity Products and Opportunity Line Items

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I read about Opportunity Object and OpportunityLineItems and sub object in Opportunity named Opportunity Product Object.Is OpportunityLineItems and Opportunity Products are same thing or different??
if different what is the difference.Please clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes they are the same : [Salesforce official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm#topic-title)

> Name: The opportunity line item name (known as “Opportunity Product” in the
>   user interface).

Comment: Is it a lookup relationship or a master-detail relationship?